# identify PK in ring signatures by using (t,n)-threshold

Tags: signature, threshold-cryptography, anonymity

Consider a group of $n$ public keys $pk_1,...,pk_n$ with corresponding secret keys $sk_1,...,sk_n$.

I'm looking for a cryptographic primitive with the following properties:

1. **Ring signature property**.

   It allows the owner of a secret key $sk_i$ to digitally sign a message in anonymous way i.e., any one validating the signature can know it validly signed by one of $pk_1,...,pk_n$ and no additional information is known about the signer.
2. **$(t,n)$-threshold revealing**.

   Any group of $t$ different secret key holders out of the group of $n$ holders can collaborate and reveal who is the true signer.
3. **No trusted setup**.

   The third property is not strict and can be relaxed.

Does anyone knows anything that may fit this properties?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74465/discussion-on-question-by-avilan-identify-pk-in-ring-signatures-by-using-t-n-t).